# How do algorithms differ from design patterns?

Tags: c, algorithm, design-patterns

I am new to C programming; coming from an OOP PHP background.

I find C to be (no wonder) a much more difficult language. I had particularly lots of problems figuring out a couple of things on arrays at first: like there is no native associative array.

Now, this part I guess I'm figuring out little by little, but now I have a question regarding a conversation I had just yesterday with a C developer. She was explaining the binary search algorithm to me because I asked her whether there were libraries to do array related stuff in C or not because it seemed like a smarter solution than always re-inventing the wheel.

I would really love to learn more about algorithms in C, in particular what differences are there between algorithms and the design patterns I'm used to using in PHP?

Comment: Why do you use so many periods?

Comment: MIT's Intro to Algorithms course is available online, and it seems to cover what you're asking: http://academicearth.org/courses/introduction-to-algorithms

Comment: @Jerry and 3) what library resources are out there. I know that last one has been answered repeatedly, and I think the first one as well. Not so sure about the second one, but the question needs fixing before it should be re-opened. As it stands it is a incoherent jumble. Let me find some links.

Comment: @la_f0ka: Here are some questions on libraries that provide a lot of the tools you are used to from higher level languages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213460/boost-like-libraries-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623455/c-common-frameworks-libraries

Comment: @la_f0ka: On getting a handle on the algorithms you need to work at a lower level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026813/how-do-i-learn-algorithms-closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085998/algorithms-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183240/what-book-to-use-to-learn-algorithms-and-data-structures

Comment: @la_f0ka: I've done a *very* heavy blue pencil job on your question to isolate the one part of it I don't believe has a clear answer on the site. If you don't like what I've done you can roll the changes back and take another crack at it yourself. In the mean time I'm voting to re-open.

Answer (score 4):

Taking things in order: the extent of C's support for anything like an associative array would be `qsort` to sort an array of structures based on a key, and `bsearch` to find one based on a key. There are, of course, quite a few alternatives -- various other libraries have hash tables, balanced trees, etc. Exactly which will suit your purposes is hard to guess though.

Offhand, I don't know of many good books covering algorithms that use C as their primary vehicle for demonstration. A few obvious recommendations for books on algorithms in general (mostly language independent) would be:

1. *The Art of Computer Programming* by Donald Knuth. This is pretty much *the* class algorithms book. It's now (finally) up to four volumes. Knuth originally started on it in 1967, planning to write 7 volumes. Only three volumes were available for a *long* time. A fourth was added *quite* recently. At the rate he's going, it's only going to make it to 7 if Knuth lives to be well past 100 years old. Nonetheless, the parts that are there are extremely good -- but (warning!) he analyzes the algorithms in *considerable* detail; if you don't know at least a little calculus, a fair amount will probably be hard to follow.
2. *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein. IIRC, there's now a newer edition than I have, which adds yet another author. This is a *large* book (dropping it on your toes would be quite painful). It uses a fair amount of mathematical notation and such throughout, but if you're willing to work a little at looking up the notation, it's really pretty understandable. It covers quite a bit of important ground (e.g., graph algorithms) that are scheduled for later volumes of Knuth, but not (at least yet) available there.
3. *Algorithms and Data Structures* by Aho, Hopcraft and Ullman. This is (by a pretty fair margin) the smallest, lightest, and at least for most people probably the easiest of these to follow.
4. Though it's only available used anymore, if you can find a copy of *Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs* by Niklaus Wirth, that's what I'd really suggest. It uses Pascal (no surprise -- Niklaus Wirth invented Pascal), but that's enough like C that it doesn't cause a real problem. It doesn't go into as much depth as Knuth about each algorithm, but still enough to give a good feel for when one is likely to be a good choice versus another. For somebody in your position (some background in programming, but little in this area) it's my top recommendation.

Though I've said it before, I think it bears repeating: IMO, all of Robert Sedgewick's books on algorithms should be avoided. *Algorithms in C++* is probably the worst of them, but the others are only marginally better. The code they include (again, especially the C++ version) is truly execrable, and the descriptions of algorithms are often incomplete and/or misleading. The most recent editions have fixed *some* of the problems, but (IMO) not nearly enough to qualify as something that should ever be recommended. If there was no alternative, you *could* probably get by with these, but given the number of alternatives that are dramatically superior, the only reason to read these at all is if somebody gives them to you, and you absolutely *can't* afford anything else.

As far as algorithms versus design patterns goes, the line *can* get blurry in places, but generally an algorithm is much more tightly defined. An algorithm will normally have a specific, tightly defined input which it processes in a specific way to produce an equally specific result/output. A design pattern tends to be more loosely defined, more generic. An algorithm can be generic as well (e.g., a sorting algorithms might require a type that defines a strict, weak ordering) but still has *specific* requirements on the type.

A design pattern tends to be somewhat more loosely defined. For example, the visitor pattern involves processing groups of objects -- but we don't want to modify the types of those objects when we decide we need to process them in a new and different way. We do that by defining the processes separately from the objects to be processed, along with how we'll traverse the groups of objects, and allow a process to work with each.

To look at it from a rather different direction, you can usually implement an algorithm with a function or a small group of functions. A design pattern tends to be oriented more toward the style in which you write your code, rather than just "here's a function, use it."

Answer (score 1):

["Algorithms in C, Parts 1-5 (Bundle): Fundamentals, Data Structures, Sorting, Searching, and Graph Algorithms (3rd Edition)"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201756080)

Cannot stress how good that series is.

Comment: Thanks a lot nacho ;). I definitely need to check on that, hope it doesn't get me too dizzy

Comment: hahaha, well, I got trolled for asking too many questions...probably the language barrier had something to do with the way I asked too...but whatever. Anyways, I appreciate the recommendations Jerry. I'll try to find those. Which one do you think I should start with?